# Master Detail Row for Grid.Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing MVC5 application. i use Grid.Mvc from CodePlex.

I have requirement to display master-detail row.

i need the details to display below the row as well as  display all detail row on click of a Expand Button.

please check the  image below.

[image]

Comment: You're asking to do your job completely, its not good. Try something by your own and add come with your efforts to clear doubts. Show us the code what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Than functionality sometimes named "Hierarchy grids". GridMVC doesn't support it. Most of paid grids have it from the box. Ext.MVC - should be the best of them

Free "jquery datatables" instead of hierarchy grids propose "expandable row" concept, that is more flexible way. There you could put any custom html form (with any type of pickers you want to edit your "one-to-many" references in data).